# Is there any way to Run vmx file over vsphere Client?

Tags: virtual-machine, vsphere, ovf

I was basically importing OVF file to Deploy OVF template but it was throwing an error *Unsupported Hardware Family* for its solution I need to convert it into vmx format now I want to know how can create VM with vmx file over Vsphere Client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you convert `OVF` to `vmx` using any tool you like you probably get more than two files in which one will be **.vmdk** that is **Virtual Disk** file import it in you data-store than create `New Custom VM` navigate through all the steps.
On selecting `Disk` select *Use an existing virtual disk* and hit next in the next window browse to you '.vmdk' thats it :)